# Best way to find out if "All Users" has view Access to current Tab in DotNetNuke

Tags: c#, dotnetnuke

I'm creating an SEO Helper module for DNN. It basically adds a note on the page to Page Editors to correct certain items on the page to help with SEO. However, I obviously don't need/want to show this information on internal pages where Google and other search engines can't access.

What's the best way to determine if "All Users" has view access to the Current Tab?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a one-liner:

```
var allCanSee = TabPermissionController.GetTabPermissions(TabId, PortalId)
   .ToList().Any(pi => pi.RoleID == -1);
```

Answer (score 1):

This will help

```
//get the TabPermission for the current tab and cast from Collection to List<TabPermissionInfo>
List<DotNetNuke.Security.Permissions.TabPermissionInfo> tabPermissionInfo = DotNetNuke.Security.Permissions.TabPermissionController.GetTabPermissions(TabId, PortalId).Cast<DotNetNuke.Security.Permissions.TabPermissionInfo>().ToList();

//loop all the permissionInfo objects and check for RoleId -1 (= all users)
bool allUsers = false;
foreach (TabPermissionInfo permissionInfo in tabPermissionInfo)
{
    if (permissionInfo.RoleID == -1)
    {
        allUsers = true;
    }

    //for visualization of all roles and id's for current tab
    Label1.Text += permissionInfo.RoleName + " - " + permissionInfo.RoleID + "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Certainly helped a lot, and using RoleID = -1  I assume would be safe and static since all installations have All Users Role pre-installed.

Comment: Yes, and it is also is the same ID on every portal, not just portal `0`

Comment: How would you detect that the page is loaded in the DNN Admin Skin (like all module EDIT pages get loaded into) ?

Comment: `if (DotNetNuke.Common.Globals.IsEditMode() == true)` perhaps? This works on normal pages.